# versioning DTO best practices

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd, versioning

What are best practices for versioning DTO's? And maybe a small sample, with serializing/ deserializing and how this versioning ensures that the code does not break? I seem to be a little lost and could not find a lot of docu on web. Thanks.

Comment: How are the DTO's used? are they being returned by WCF services?

Comment: nope, no wcf involvement so far.